# OSC送信を行いたいです。

Tags: python, 深層学習

python-oscを用いて、Muse2という脳波計で計測した脳波を、スマホからOSC通信を用いて、PCヘ送りcsvで記録したいです。

今詰まっているのは、OSCメッセージを送るところです。
以下のコードを見てください。
最後にMarkerを送信して、recoringを制御しています。
しかし一向にcsvファイルへの書き込みが進みません。

これはmarkerが送られていないためだと思っています。
何かアイデアがあれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

```
    """


 Mind Monitor - EEG OSC Receiver
    Coded: James Clutterbuck (2022)
    Requires: pip install python-osc
    """
    from datetime import datetime
import time
    from pythonosc import dispatcher, osc_server ,udp_client
    
    ip = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 5009
    filePath = 'OSC-Python-Recording.csv'
    auxCount = -1
    recording = False
    
    f = open (filePath,'w+')
    
    def writeFileHeader():
        global auxCount
        fileString = 'TimeStamp,RAW_TP9,RAW_AF7,RAW_AF8,RAW_TP10,'
        for x in range(0,auxCount):
            fileString += 'AUX'+str(x+1)+','
        fileString +='Marker\n'
        f.write(fileString)
    
    def eeg_handler(address: str,*args):
        global recording
        global auxCount
        if auxCount==-1:
            auxCount = len(args)-4
            writeFileHeader()
        if recording:
            timestampStr = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            fileString = timestampStr
            for arg in args:
                fileString += ","+str(arg)            
            fileString+="\n"
            f.write(fileString)
        
    def marker_handler(address: str,i):
        global recording
        global auxCount
        timestampStr = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        markerNum = address[-1]
        if recording:
            fileString = timestampStr+',,,,,'
            for x in range (0,auxCount):
                fileString +=','
            fileString +='/Marker/'+markerNum+"\n"
            f.write(fileString)
        if (markerNum=="1"):        
            recording = True
            print("Recording Started.")
        if (markerNum=="2"):
            f.close()
            recording = False
            server.shutdown()
            print("Recording Stopped.")    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
        dispatcher.map("/muse/eeg", eeg_handler)
        dispatcher.map("/Marker/*", marker_handler)
    
        server = osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer((ip, port), dispatcher)
        print("Listening on UDP port "+str(port)+"\nSend Marker 1 to Start recording and Marker 2 to Stop Recording.")
        server.serve_forever()

        client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient("0.0.0.0", 5009)
        client.send_message("/Marker/1", 1) # start recording
        time.sleep(60)
        client.send_message("/Marker/2", 2) # end recording
```

Comment: サーバ側の UDP ポート番号が 5000 でクライアント側が 5009 になっていますが、それらは合わせなくても問題ないのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとございます。
自分のコピペミスです。
実行時は、合わせていました。
質問記事の方に反映させておきます。

Comment: `server.serve_forever()` でクライアントからの接続待ち状態になっています。なので、`client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient("0.0.0.0", 5009)` 以降の部分を別のプログラムコードにして実行するとよいかと。